# Use input text instead of selected list

Tags: angularjs

Instead of using the following:

```
<select class="form-control" disabled>
<option ng-repeat="category in Categories" value="category.id" ng-selected="APIdata.category_id  === category.id">{{ category.name }}
</option>
</select>
```

is it possible to use an **input text only** since the above selected list is disabled and there is no possibility of changing its value? `Categories and APIdata` are properties(Categories is an array and APIdata is an object) of $scope. How should we do that?

Comment: Can you clarify on what you want to achieve; what is the text input you're referring to? How does the select relate to the text input?

Comment: I just want to replace the above code with an input text. That's all!

Comment: Uh - we don't know anything about the context here so we don't even know what the text input is supposed to represent, but okay, let's try. If you replace all of the code you provided with `<input type="text">`, is it enough for you? Or does the text input actually need to *do* something?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your controller in the right place:

```
$scope.category = $scope.Categories.filter(c => c.id === $scope.APIdata.category_id)[0];
```

Change your view:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="category" disabled/>
```